# How can I prevent RadioGroup event?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

I have a RadioGroup

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/typeGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/type0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="type0" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/type1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="type1" />

</RadioGroup>
```

This is the program, can I ask user to confirm change, if no, the radio button should not be changed, is there function like preventDefault of javascript?

```
typeGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.typeGroup);

typeGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            type=group.indexOfChild((RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId));

            //dialog confirm change
            //if yes, keep going
            //if no, stop event

        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **alertDialog**, in case the user accepts then you do the radio group selection, or nothing otherwise. Here is an example:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CompeticionActivityPartidoMain.this);
              builder.setTitle("Dialog").setMessage("Are you sure?")
                  .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                              dialog.dismiss();
                              radiogroup.clearCheck();
                             }
                      })
                   .setPositiveButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              // Here your code
                              switch (type) {
                                   case 0:
                                        size=2;
                                        break;
                                   case 1:
                                        size=1;
                                        break;
                              }
                           }
                     });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                }
            });
```

I hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Sorry this is not useful, I edited the code in question, I don't want the size confuse you, I need the function to stop the change event

Comment: I just tried `typeGroup.clearCheck()`, `group.clearCheck()`, both will crash the app. Also, from the function name, I guess it will uncheck all radiobutton in the group, that is not what I want.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the exception you get?

Comment: I think it repeating check and uncheck, 
Process: com.recordbutton, PID: 763
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:168)
            at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
            at com.testradio.MainActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)